# Passenger logging and STDOUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

When developing rails applications I usually use `thin` for my development environment. I like `thin` because the logs are not outputed directly on STDOUT but instead written in `log/{development,production}.log`.

Sometimes I just insert a `p <some object>` inside a controller's action just to have a quick look at some object and debug my code. I know that I could use the rails loggin api but I don't want to do that when for every request you get 1000+ loggin lines.

On my production servers I used thin in the past (I configured apache to work as a proxy for my `thin` instances). In the `log` directory `thin` created a file called `thin.log` where you can see `thin`'s STDOUT-output.

But in new production server I started using Passenger for my production environment. `log/production.log` is created and I can see the logs the whole time. But what I really would want to do is to see somewhere Passaneger's STDOUT-output, to get something like `log/passenger.log` (like `thins` does).

I've already searched in google about this but I couldn't find anything useful there. Is there a way I could archive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems that nobody knows if this is possible I found [here](http://bigtablet.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-log-in-passenger/) something that works for me fine.