# How to access console (stdout) of a Rails app when starting nginx with Passenger and Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, console, bundler

I use Phusion Passenger to run a Rails application. I have a confing in the nginx directory, so when I restart nginx I get my Rails application running.

However, I have some problems with the app, so I would like to look into the console for error output. If I run the Rails application with explicitly `passenger start` command within the Rails app directory - then no error occurs.

So I need to get live output from the console when the Rails app is running with nginx.

The problem is: no file is going written in my download directory within the Rails public directory (i.e. `./public/downloads/...`). I write the file using:

```
open(file_path, 'wb') do |file| 
 ...
 file << open(url)
 ...
end
```

If somebody knows why the error could occur when running not with `passenger start`, but with `sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload`, it would be great to understand the cause.

## Update:

I see it is writing to the `log/passenger.3000.log`. But is it possible to connect some terminal directly to the app, as passenger is connected?

## Update 2:

Wrong! The `log/passenger.3000.log` is going written when I start the application with `passenger start`. But the `log/development.log` is the one I searched for. And it is possible to watch the file with either `tail -f log/development.log` or with `watch tail log/development.log`

Comment: does it not write to Rails logger?

Comment: it does, but occasionally I did all the logging with `puts` (yep, shame on me...) And now I need the console to look what is going there with the app. How to show the log file in real time?

Comment: to view log file in real time: go to app folder on the production server and do `tail -f log/production.log`. In apache the puts within an app are logged in the apache's `error.log` file in `/var/log/apache/` folder. Check somethign liek that for `nginx`

Comment: I already tried that (found also on the SO). But it doesn't update the file ...

Comment: Also see this: http://bigtablet.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-log-in-passenger/

Comment: @tihom could you please post your both proposals as an answer? also the `tail -f log/passenger.3000.log` was not working, because I was wrong about where does the passenger write the logs when it is started from nginx, not from the explicit command `passenger start`

Comment: the `tail -f log/development.log` (my fault)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passenger logging and STDOUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956651/passenger-logging-and-stdout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view the log files real time by going to app folder on the production server and do `tail -f log/production.log`.

You may also overwrite the `stdout` for the app in production environment file as suggested [here](http://bigtablet.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-log-in-passenger/):

```
std_out = File.new(RAILS_ROOT + "/log/stdout.log","a")
$stdout.reopen(std_out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Passenger sends logs entries, including output from the application, to the web server's log file.

For example, with Nginx, this is the global Nginx error log file. You can instead configure Passenger to send log output to a specific file using the [passenger_log_file](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_log_file) directive.

More info: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/log_file/

You can set the destination of this output using Nginx's [error_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) directive. It can be sent directly to a remote syslog server such as Papertrail's.